# The numbering of the sections appear only in the first section

Tags: latex

I'm having a problem with the numbering of the sections in latex.

I want the numbering of the chapters and sections to be as

1 first chapter

1.1 first section

1.2 second section

the problem is that the numbering of the section appears only in the first section and I have no idea why is this happening!

this is the code that I used.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for numbering of pages
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % for the chapters numbering 

%margins 
%1 inch from top, buttom and right side of the page and 1.5 inch from left side of the page

 \geometry{
 a4paper,
left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in
 }



\onehalfspacing
\centering
\pagenumbering{roman}



\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

  \titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

  \titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}



\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\number\numexpr\value{section}\relax}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\number\numexpr\value{subsection}\relax}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\number\numexpr\value{subsubsection}\relax}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}% Not using chapters, but they're used in the counte

\begin{document}

% this is the table of contents of the document 

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
%--------------------------------------------------
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

% this is the introduction chapter
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter*{\centering \vspace{80 mm} Chapter One: Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Chapter One: Introduction}%
\newpage

\justify
 \setlength{\parindent}{5 ex} 
\section{Introduction}
%write introduction here 

\section{Problem Definition}
%write Problem Definition here


\section{Aim and Objectives}
%write Aim and Objectives here 

\section{Methodology}

%write Methodology here 


\section{Project Scope}

%write Project Scope here 

\section{Project Timeline}

%write Project Timeline  here 

\section{Conclusion}

%write Conclusion  here 

\end{document}
```

the table of contentes shows the numbring however the numbers appear only in the first section (introduction). how can I make the numbers appear in the other sections as well ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the following package and code affects the numbering of the section (I have no idea why is that happening). when I removed the following code the numbering of the sections appeared in the headings also.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

  \titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

  \titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

now I need to find another way to change the font size of the headings. I would appreciate it if any one posts a better way to chanage the font size without using  `titlesec` package.

Comment: I have just came across this and I can confirm that simply changing section headings with titlesec like this does affect section numbering